# How to add view (by window manager) in work manager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am new in work manager and I want to add new overlay window from work manager
I am using below code but unable to add overlay window

class DummyWorker(
val context: Context,
val parameters: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, parameters) {

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Looper.prepare()
        val mWindowManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val viewFinder = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null) as Button
        val windowManagerFlagOverlay =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY else
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
        val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100,
            windowManagerFlagOverlay,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP
        mWindowManager.addView(viewFinder, layoutParams)
    delay(10000)
    return Result.success()
}
```

}

Comment: First request overlay permission then addView to windowmanager

Comment: yes, it has already requested and accepted. View added successfully to windowmanager in activity but not in work manager